# How to find uncertainty of slope and y-intercept of linear fit from uncertainty of data

Tags: physics

I know how to find the slope and the y-intercept of a linear fit of some data by least squares. What I can’t find is how to calculate the uncertainty of these two quantities given the uncertainties of the data.

`

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. But we would need to know more about the "uncertainty in data" you mentioned.

Comment: Explore jackknife estimation.

Comment: Nevermind, found it

Comment: @SantiagoGonzalez What did you find? I am also curious about this question

Comment: I found a book, but it's in spanish.